# rails 4 strong params error: param not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, strong-parameters

Im trying to accomplish some functionality in the update method of my model. However, I am getting the following errors which seem to be due to the strong parameter convention introduced in rails 4.

```
 Upload.rb (Model)
 Update method 

  def update
mode = nil
market = nil
case @upload.task_id
when 1
    mode = "channel"
    market = nil
when 2
    mode = "national"
    market = "national"
when 3
    mode = "regional"
    market = "t"
when 4
    mode = "regional"
    market = "c"
when 5
    mode = "regional"
    market = "e"
when 6
    mode = "regional"
    market = "v"
else
    puts"Error!! Received invalid task.id to parse"
end
options = Hash[:file_path =>Upload.find(params[:id]).f_path , :mode =>"#{mode}", :market=>"#{market}"]
puts "options= #{options.inspect}"
@cp = CsvParser.new(options)

if @upload.update(upload_params)
       redirect_to @upload, notice: 'Upload was successfully updated.'
    else
       render action: 'edit'
    end
  end


  # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:sourcedata, :task_id, :status, :file_path, :options, :mode, :market)
    end
```

Error

```
    ActionController::ParameterMissing - param not found: upload:

    actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:173:in `require'
```

What am I doing wrong in the above code. Why cant I send my params through. What should I tweak to make this work. Im a bit confused about the strong params and would appreciate it if someone has any advice. Googling around on the internet I got unrelated stuff so wondering if someone can help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`ActionController::ParameterMissing` is basically saying that the current request didn't comply with `params.require(:upload)` i.e. params[:upload] is not present.

Looks like the issue is not on your **update** action but on your **edit** action or within the edit view in the way you are building the form. You should post your `def edit` code and the edit.html.erb or whatever view is building the update form to further troubleshoot this.